# How do I change all of the cursors on my PC, not just the ones in customize settings in Windows 10 (Home)?

Tags: windows, windows-10, mouse, cursor

OS: Windows 10 Home

I know how to do the basic customization of the cursor, I have changed all of that. what I want now is to customize all the rest of the cursors, like grab, zoom-in, and especially middle mouse scroll. (the circle with the arrows when you middle click) I want to know if there is any way.

To clarify *not* the cursors under “Settings -> Mouse -> Additional Mouse Properties -> Pointers.” Those I have already done. It’s the others like the grabbing hand and the magnifying glass.

Comment: Stardock's [Cursor FX](https://www.stardock.com/products/cursorfx/)

Comment: This is a cool program, but unfortunately it only changes the basic cursor stuff like "move", "resize", "select", "arrow", all of that is in settings already. It doesn't have the zoom-in or any of the other more obscure cursors i was looking for

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aside from the 17 system-wide cursors that you have already found, each program that uses additional cursors provides its own, stored as resources in the program’s files.

Modifying those hard-coded cursors requires a resource editor/compiler. Two that I like are [Resource Hacker](https://angusj.com/resourcehacker/) and [Greenfish Icon Editor Pro](http://greenfishsoftware.org/gfie.php) (which does cursors too).

Note that cursors are not necessarily in the program’s main `.exe`. For example, Firefox cursors are in `C:\Program Files\Mozilla Firefox\xul.dll`.

Comment: Aaaah thank you!!! I'll definitely check those programs out. So they are Chrome cursors? I understand now! Do you happen to know where Chromes are located?